# It is possible for Keycloak to be used as an SP and Google as IDP

Tags: keycloak, saml, idp, google-sso

jenkins
instead of signing into jenkins using username/ password credentials, we sign into google workspace and access jenkins in the same manner i want keycloak to work as SP

keycloak
instead of signing into keycloak using username/ password credentials, we sign into google workspace and access keycloak